# How can I interrupt startup spring-boot application if kafka topic name from properties does not exist in kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I try to check Kafka topics on startup spring-boot application. I want to throw an exception and interrupt startup. It is my config:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin;
    private final TopicProperties topicProperties;

    public KafkaTopicConfig(KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin, TopicProperties topicProperties) {
        this.kafkaAdmin = kafkaAdmin;
        this.topicProperties = topicProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(kafkaAdmin.getConfig());

        ListTopicsResult listTopicsResult = admin.listTopics();
        listTopicsResult.names().whenComplete((existTopics, throwable) -> {
            log.info("TOPICS LOAD: {}", existTopics.size());
            topicProperties.getTopics().forEach((s, topic) -> {
                if (!existTopics.contains(topic))
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Topic with name: " + topic + " not found in kafka.");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But after throws `throw new IllegalStateException("Topic with name: " + topic + " not found in kafka.");` this exception ignored and application continue works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ApplicationRunner`, implement `SmartLifecycle` with `autoStartup=true` and put your logic in `start()`.